# Is comma needed before 'and' in this sentence?

Tags: commas, conjunctions, clauses, oxford-comma

We use comma in lists. Apart from that, comma is needed before and when joining two independent clauses. For example: I want to write, and I have stamps. Here I am clearly joining two independent clauses and need comma before and.

However, I am confused in this sentence:

> The Language Study classes introduced me to the English, French, and German languages **and** motivated me to learn other languages.

In the above sentence, I am not sure whether I am joining two independent clauses and therefore a comma is needed before boldfaced and.

Comment: You would not use a comma before "and" in that sentence.  You would only do so if, for example, you inserted a "they" between "and" and "motivated," making "and" and that which follows a coordinate clause.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry for the repeated articles, now fixed that.

Comment: @Benjamin Harman. I've come across style-guides that would consider the comma here optional. According to less prescriptivist authors, where presence or lack of a comma would not distinguish readings, commas may be used purely to indicate pauses and/or make reading easier. But this has been discussed here before.

Comment: Is *motivated me to learn other languages* an independent clause?

Answer (score 0):

The sentence is correctly punctuated. A comma before the first *and* is optional and is called a 'serial comma' or an 'Oxford comma' - i.e., a comma put before the conjunction separating the last two list elements. A comma before the second *and* is not needed - it is not joining clauses (a **subject** AND a predicate) but list elements (namely, *introduced* and *motivated* - two predicates describing the same noun, *the classes*) in a list containing less than three (two) elements.